# How to check duplicate row value in SQLite Table?

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

At the time of button click i am inserting edit text value to SQLite database.At the time of inserting i want to check that the same data is available in the table ,if it is available means i don't want to insert otherwise insert the records to table

Please any one help me with some source code
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's your criteria for two rows being "the same".

Comment: I want to check the available data and new data is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a better solution is to declare each column you want to consider (when determining if a row is a duplicate) `UNIQUE`. Then SQLite will handle this problem for you.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: Yes, you should be able to handle this through setting up your table's unique structure.  If you have unique keys, then wrap your SQL insert in error-handling, and if it throw's a unique constraint error, you know the data is already in the table, and you can gracefully handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to do a SQL compare instead of setting up the table to have a unique structure, try this:

1) determine what makes your row unique.
In my example, column 1 (C1) and column 2 (C2) makes the unique criteria.

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE T1 
WHERE T1.C1 NOT IN 
  (SELECT T2.C1 FROM YOURTABLE T2 
    WHERE T2.C1 = T1.C1
     AND T2.C2 = T1.C2)
```